# Which kind of SSL certificate is the big one?

Tags: tls

Okay, so I just recently visited a couple of https (secure) websites and noticed that there was a difference with the way they were shown in Chrome.

[image]

[image]

As you can see, the top one has some extra text next to it. How is it possible and can I use it if I have an AlphaSSL Private SSL certificate for my website on a shared server?

Answer (score 6, accepted):

This is an [EV Certificate](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Extended_Validation_Certificate). You pay more for it, and you are rewarded with a green rectangle in some browsers.